# What is big O for the merge part of mergesort?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, big-o

Two lists `a` and `b` such that both `len(a) + len(b) == 5` and `merge(a,b)` does only one comparison. What is th Big O notation for this?

Comment: Big O is not applicable. Big O describes growth, while your input sizes are fixed.

Comment: Each merge takes `O(N)`, each partition also takes `O(N)`. You merge and partition a total of `O(logN)` times for total complexity `O(NlogN)`

Comment: Merging two lists is O(a+b)unless you merge linked lists,then it *can* be as low as O(min(a,b))

Answer (score 3):

Big O notation does not consider a fixed size input. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

> In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms according to how their running time or space requirements grow as the input size grows.

When merging two sorted lists, the number of comparisons needed depends on the size of the list. Merging two lists of length *n* requires roughly *n* comparisons.

In Big O notation this results in a complexity of O(n)